# How can I write a grok pattern for this log?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Log:

`[2021-01-27T11:51:18,838][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"C:\\Pippo\\logstash-7.6.1\\data\\dead_letter_queue"}`

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) online tool that will be very usefull for this kind of use case.
This is a first grok expression that match with a must part of your data line :

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:level} \]\[%{GREEDYDATA:class}\] %{GREEDYDATA:action} \{:setting=>"%{GREEDYDATA:setting}", :path=>"%{PATH:path}"\}
```

This expression it's a starting point to your use case. The result of this grok expression is this :

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2021-01-27T11:51:18,838"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2021"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "27"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "11",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "51",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "18,838"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "level": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "class": [
    [
      "logstash.setting.writabledirectory"
    ]
  ],
  "action": [
    [
      "Creating directory"
    ]
  ],
  "setting": [
    [
      "path.dead_letter_queue"
    ]
  ],
  "path": [
    [
      "C:\\Pippo\\logstash-7.6.1\\data\\dead_letter_queue"
    ]
  ],
  "UNIXPATH": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "WINPATH": [
    [
      "C:\\Pippo\\logstash-7.6.1\\data\\dead_letter_queue"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I dont't know to use grok debug how does it work? don't have result from it  @YLR

Comment: Follow the link, put your data line at the top, and paste the expression below. The result display at the bottom.

Comment: the answer is no matches, why?, thanks for the help

Comment: It match "something", you haven't explain what you want extract from this data line, so I'm not sure that just it.

Comment: I want extract everything in the data line. All in between the square brackets. Thanks, in advance. @YLR

Comment: Ok, so it's done ;), this grok epxression works

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Can you show a screen?Thanks a lot @YLR

Comment: I've add the result of the grok in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all. in your opinion, you can get a reverse from a log line? @YLR

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse" ?

Comment: i mean given a pattern you can get the log line. or the reverse procedure?Thank yo@YLR

Comment: USe this tool http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to test. And it provides a discover feature.

Comment: Thanks for your competence.